# Cloudboost - Library Error

Tags: cloudboost

Something strange happened yesterday afternoon, all of a sudden I started getting errors when just loading the cloudboost.js library.

This is the error, and I've included basic html with just the library in that is giving me this error - And the Link to the URL: http://oiapp.co.za/test-cloudboost/

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
at CloudBoost._CB2.default.fromJSON (cloudboost.js:6238)
at CloudBoost._CB2.default.fromJSON (cloudboost.js:6199)
at Function._CB2.default.CloudUser._getCurrentUser (cloudboost.js:18276)
at Object.defineProperty.value (cloudboost.js:18371)
at __webpack_require__ (cloudboost.js:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (cloudboost.js:81)
at __webpack_require__ (cloudboost.js:30)
at cloudboost.js:50
at cloudboost.js:53
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (cloudboost.js:9)
at cloudboost.js:10
```

This is my Source for the HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <![endif]-->
    <title>Cloudboost - Test</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cloudboost.io/js-sdk/cloudboost.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error on my end. Can you try incognito.

[image]

Comment: That is the strange part, I go into incognito, no error. The minute I try use the login system through cloudboost on my actual site, I start getting the error. Go back to this test page, still getting the error.

What gets cached that could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe the older version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else comes across this problem, I had an address, full name & geopoint as custom fields in my user table. I've removed those and everything is working perfectly.

Strange, anyway will be using a custom table to store extra user information now.

Comment: Also, remember to clear out any stored data from your website to clear the cloudboost error.